# An unexpected empty line appears after using Clang-Format to sort includes

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I'm using Clang-Format through clangd extension in vscode.
Turn on the "SortIncludes" function of Clang-Format, and then using it to format the C++ code, I saw:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main()
```

turn into:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
```

An empty line appeared. If you format the code again, that line just disappear.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
```

How could I get rid of that empty line?